# ui -router update the current state for abstract parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router for maintaining the state in my application. The application has one abstract parent state and few child states. Parent state has got some resolves (working fine), now since I have a parent `abstract` state I can only navigate to a specific child which is updated in the `$state.current` property by default when I navigate to child state.

The Resolve in the parent might give some data based on which I don't want to navigate to the current child but to some other state. Like an auth error kind of use case, although I can use `$state.go()` to navigation to auth state but current child state still gets fired, any way to update the current child state and not let it fire the default child state.

Comment: navigating to the child state should not fire another state unless it is a [great][grand]parent of this state. You should show some code

Comment: @Ladmerc consider i have parent/child, with parent having some resolves. Now based on those resolves, is there a way to stop navigation to parent/child and have parent/child1.

Comment: has anybody come across this use case